# Выводит несколько раз

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, вывод

Задача: надо вывести индексы одинаковых элементов одномерного массива. Выводит всё корректно, но несколько раз, так как проходит все элементы цикла. Как исправить это?

Ввод:

```
Enter number of array's elements:  5
Enter 0 element of the array:  2
Enter 1 element of the array:  8
Enter 2 element of the array:  6
Enter 3 element of the array:  25
Enter 4 element of the array:  8
```

Вывод:

```
1 4 
4 1
```

Код:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define bool _Bool

int main() 
{
    int N; //количество элементов массива
    int i, j; //итераторы циклов
    bool solutionExists = 0;
    bool solutionExistsHere = 0;
    printf("Enter number of array's elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &N); //считывание N 

    int A[N]; //массив по условию
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {//считывание элементов массива
        printf("Enter %d element of the array: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {//внешний цикл перебора элементов
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {//внутренний цикл перебора элементов
            if (A[i] == A[j] && j != i)
            {//два элемента равны, а их индексы не равны
                (!solutionExistsHere) ? printf("%d ", i) : printf(""); // печать текущего индекса из внешного массива
                printf("%d ", j);
                solutionExists = 1;
                solutionExistsHere = 1;
            }
        }

        (solutionExistsHere && i + 1 < N) ? printf("\n") : printf(""); //печатает перевод строки, если что-то было выведено в этой итерации
        solutionExistsHere = 0;
    }

    if(!solutionExists) printf("no solution");
    return 0;
}
```

Возможно ли как-то решить данный недочёт без особых костылей?

Comment: @entithat ну так мне нужны индексы элементов из текущего массива или я что-то не понял?

Comment: ах да, я подумал, что значения надо :) Пардон ..

Comment: Сделайте вложенный цикл начиная с i, а не с нуля: `for(j = i; j < N; ++j)`

Comment: @Vladimir Если использовать данных подход, то проблема решается только если одинаковых элементов == 2. Иначе вывод становится не корректным: [скриншот](https://prnt.sc/igdkrz)

Answer (score 0):

Улучшил код. Он сравнивает все элементы, но без повторов.

**UPD: упростил код.**

```
int main() {
    int N = 10;
    int A[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,0,2,0,5};
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {//внешний цикл перебора элементов
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {//внутренний цикл перебора элементов
            if (A[i] == A[j])
            {//два элемента равны
                printf("A[%d]=%d and A[%d]=%d is equals\n", i, A[i], j, A[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, данный код работает корректно, если повторяющихся элементов одного типа две штуки

Comment: @Dan, Проверьте такой код. Или вы хотите, чтобы решение разом вывело список индексов массива с одинаковым содержимым? К примеру желаемый вывод: `В ячейках 2,4,8 значение 2012`

Answer (score 0):

Было бы хорошо, если бы автор сразу все условия указал... А так не ясно, какие конструкции можно применять и какое насилие над исходным массивом допустимо. Если массив можно портить, то могу предложить такое решение - выбрать первый (например) элемент маркером и потом найденные совпадения менять на этот маркер. Если же исходный массив портить нельзя, то можно его предварительно скопировать. За основу я взял алгоритм автора вопроса.
Вот как-то так получилось. Вроде работает с разными наборами.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init(int *a, int n);

#define N 12

int main() 
{
    int A[N] = {1,6,3,1,6,3,1,6,3,1,4,5}; // это был образец массива от автора вопроса
    init(A, N);

    int is_found = 0, is_first_printed = 0;
    int marker = A[0];
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i < N; i++)
        printf("A[%2d] = %d\n", i, A[i]);
    printf("\n" );

    for(i=1; i < N; i++)
        if(A[i] == marker) {
            if (!is_first_printed){
                printf("%d ", 0); // мы же взяли 0 индекс как маркер
                is_first_printed = 1;
            } else ;
            printf("%d ", i);
        } else ;
    if (is_first_printed) 
        printf("\n");

    is_first_printed=0;
    for(i=0; i < N; i++){
        for(j=0; j < N; j++){
            if ((A[i] == A[j]) && (i!=j) && (A[i]!=marker)){
                if(!is_first_printed) {
                    printf("%d ", i);
                    is_first_printed = 1;   
                } else ;
                printf("%d ", j);
                A[j] = marker;
                is_found=1;
            } else ;
        }

        if(is_found) {
            printf("\n");
            A[i] = marker;
        } else ;
        is_found=0;
        is_first_printed = 0;   
    }

    return 0;
}  

void init(int *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Простой квадратичный алгоритм без дополнительной памяти и маркеров в исходном массиве.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Печать индексов элементов массива, встречающихся 2 и более раз
// Печатаем индексы дубликатов в одной строке
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = 0;
  do {
    fputs("enter array size: ", stdout); fflush(stdout);
  } while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n <= 0);
  if (n <= 0)
    return 1;

  int i, a[n];
  puts("enter array:");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (scanf("%d", a + i) != 1) {
      puts("input error");
      return 2;
    }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int print_it = 0, j;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
      if (a[i] == a[j]) {
        if (j < i)
          break;           // этот элемент ранее уже печатали
        if (j > i) {       // а вот и очередной дубликат i-го элемента
          if (!print_it) { // "заголовок строки"
            print_it++;
            printf("values %d are in indexes: %d", a[i], i);
          }
          printf(" %d", j);
        }
      }
    if (print_it)
      puts("");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Пример запуска

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc t.c -Wall && ./a.out
enter array size: 7
enter array:
1 22 1 22 22 3 6
values 1 are in indexes: 0 2
values 22 are in indexes: 1 3 4
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```